# Was iblis the only high ranking jinn who was told to prostrate to Adam (a.s.)?

Tags: shaitan, jinn, prophet-adam

As muslims, we all know that the angels weren't the only ones who were told to prostrate to Adam (a.s.). Iblis was also one of them due to his high rank. But was he the only high ranking jinn among them? Were there other high ranking jinns who were told to prostrate to Adam (a.s.)?

Answer (score -1):

No, he was not the only one. It is clearly told that every creature in the skies (that includes all the angels and jinnat) was made to prostrate to Adam (A.S) but Iblis was the only one to refuse.

Comment: Please cite a source for your claim.

Comment: @UmH http://www.alim.org/library/biography/stories/content/SOP/10/1/Adam/Angels'%20Prostrate%20in%20Front%20of%20Adam

Comment: I don't see any evidence in your link saying that "every creature in the skies was made to prostrate". Only Iblis and the angels are mentioned and this is all the qur'an has told us.